# How to simplify this big-O notation?

Tags: computer-science, approximation, computational-complexity

I am computing the running time of an algorithm I'm analyzing. This algorithm calls $m$ times a function of running time $O(m)^{(m+3)^2}$, so we get the running time $mO(m)^{(m+3)^2}$. Can I simplify this expression? I would love to get the $m$ into the big-O-notation, but the exponent outside of the big-O throws me off. I know that $O(m)$ means there exist constants $c, m_0$ such that for all $m \geq m_0$ we have that $m \leq c*m$, but then I get stuck.

Comment: Use $O(f)\cdot O(g)=O(f\cdot g)$.

Comment: With this I get: $m O(m)^{(m+3)^2}=O(m^{(m+3)^2+1})$ which already looks a lot better - thank you! Is there a way to simplify the exponent?

Comment: It's possible to found upper bound, for example $O\Big(m^{8m^2}\Big)$, but I cannot say will be it "good" for Your task or not.

Comment: Right now I am just optimizing readability. So finding exponents that are higher but easier to read is right now preferable to me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: $(1+\epsilon)m$ is eventually larger than $m+3$ for any $\epsilon>0$, so you can write $O\left(m^{(m+3)^2}\right)=O\left(m^{((1+\epsilon)m)^2}\right)$. If it's any $\epsilon>0$, that applies to the square root of $(1+\epsilon)$ too, so we can write $O\left(m^{(m+3)^2}\right)=O\left(m^{(1+\epsilon)m^2}\right)$. You can now incorporate your $m$ calls to obtain $mO\left(m^{(1+\epsilon)m^2}\right) = O\left(m^{1+(1+\epsilon)m^2}\right)$ and state $O\left(m^{(m+3)^2}\right)= O\left(m^{cm^2}\right)$ for any $c>1$.

Comment: Thank you for this ansewr!